# TTS for Indian languages like Hindi in Java or .Net

Tags: text-to-speech

We are looking for a text-to-speech engine which can produce good quality sound files for Indian languages like Hindi, Tamil, Marathi either in Java or any other platform for offline use.

For English, there is an abundance of Text-to-Speech engines but not able to get any for language like Hindi.